# When downloading 'TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene' package, lazy loading error appears, what do?

Tags: r, r-package, bioconductor

Code:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene")
```

> Error:package or namespace load failed for 'GenomicFeatures' in
> library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):  No object DLL
> 'BiocParallel'：Is this architecture not installed? stay of execution
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package
> 'TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene'

Comment: Do you have the package `GenomicFeatures` in your system? What happens if you install it before  `xDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene'`? Try: `BiocManager::install("GenomicFeatures")`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GenomicFeatures’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): There is no DLL 'BiocParallel' : is this schema not installed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. The package should install all dependencies by default. Have you tried: update all the packages, upgrade R and then: `BiocManager::install("TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene", dependencies = TRUE)`. What version of r and what operating system do you use?.

Comment: Also check if you have installed `Rtools` and if it is in the path (I suspect you are using Windows)